# Issues append data to a .csv File using C#

Tags: c#, csv

I am manipulating a csv file using C# but I have an issue. When I added a new row, the first iteration does successful, but the second one overwrite the same row previous.

Example CSV File:

Name, LastName, Age

David, Todd, 28

Juan, Perez, 30

---

First iteration:

Name, LastName, Age

David, Todd, 28

Juan, Perez, 30

Pepe, Hernandez, 32

---

Second iteration:

Name, LastName, Age

David, Todd, 28

Juan, Perez, 30

Pepe, Hernandez, 32Maria,Lopez,35

---

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
string newFileName = "C:\\names.csv";
string nameDetails = txtName.Text + "," + txtLastName.Text + "," + txtAge.Text;
if (!File.Exists(newFileName))
{

    string nameHeader = "Name" + "," + 
    "LastName" + "," + "Age" + Environment.NewLine;

    File.WriteAllText(newFileName, nameHeader);

}    

File.AppendAllText(newFileName, nameDetails);
```

Thanks!

Comment: File.WriteAllText overwrites your file each time, use AppendAllText instead.  Write the header in first case if !Exists

Comment: @CRice writealltext is only called if the file does not exist

Comment: Seems I missed that due to bad formatting that is now fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing

```
+ Environment.NewLine
```

while calling

```
File.AppendAllText
```

It should be there as well i.e. it should be

```
File.AppendAllText(newFileName, nameDetails + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Thanks The shooter, simplest solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code to the following:

```
string newFileName = "C:\\names.csv";
string nameDetails = txtName.Text + "," + txtLastName.Text + "," + txtAge.Text;
if (!File.Exists(newFileName))
{
    string nameHeader = "Name,LastName,Age\n"; //No point concatenating
    nameDetails = nameHeader + nameDetails;
}
File.AppendAllText(newFileName, nameDetails);
```

**Side Note:**
You can keep things a bit more tidy by using `string.Format`. If you do, your code will become something like this:

```
string newFileName = "C:\\names.csv";
string nameDetails = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}\n", txtName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtAge.Text);
if (!File.Exists(newFileName))
{
    nameDetails = "Name,LastName,Age\n" + nameDetails;
}
File.AppendAllText(newFileName, nameDetails);
```

And if you're using the latest **c# 6**, things can be made even nicer:

```
string newFileName = "C:\\names.csv";
string nameDetails = $"{txtName.Text},{txtLastName.Text},{txtAge.Text}\n");
if (!File.Exists(newFileName))
{
    nameDetails = "Name,LastName,Age\n" + nameDetails;
}
File.AppendAllText(newFileName, nameDetails);
```